# how to return a query mono with the code below with java reactor

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Imagine that I have several filters and I need several `if` to validate if the value is present, and if it is, I add a criteria each time it is present and at the end of the flow I return a query.

I would then need to go through each of the filters, see if the value is present and then add a criterion.

**How would I do this without using `if` and using only Java's Reactor powers?**

I can use `filter, map, filterWhen, zipWhen etc.`

```
private Mono<Query> createQueryWithFilters(Filters filters) {
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    Query query = new Query();

    if (filters.getName().isPresent()) {
        query.addCriteria(criteria.and("name")
                .regex(filters.getName().get()));
    }

    if (filters.getAge().isPresent()) {
        query.addCriteria(criteria.and("age")
                .regex(filters.getAge().get()));
    }
    
    return Mono.just(query);
}
```

In the code above I want to return without using if and I would like to instantiate `Query()` and `Criteria()` in the stream using `Mono` or `Flux`.

**An example of coding is the one below, you can see that it is very readable and the code is more beautiful.**

**Code pattern example:**

```
public Mono<TaskDTO> getTaskById(String configId, String taskId) {
    return configRepository.findById(configId)
            .switchIfEmpty(error(notFoundException(IAC_CONFIG_NOT_FOUND_ERROR_MSG)))
            .map(Config::getTasks)
            .filter(v -> v.stream().anyMatch(t -> Objects.equals(t.getId(), taskId)))
            .switchIfEmpty(error(notFoundException(IAC_TASK_NOT_FOUND_MSG)))
            .map(v -> v.stream().findAny())
            .filter(Optional::isPresent)
            .map(v -> taskConverter.convert(v.get()));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this solution.

```
        private static final Map<String, Function<Filter, Criteria>>
                FILTERS = new HashMap<>();
    
        static {
            FILTERS.put("NAME", value -> Criteria.where("name").regex((String) value.getValue()));
            FILTERS.put("AGE", value -> Criteria.where("age").is(value.getValue()));
        }
    
      public Mono<Query> createQueryWithFilters(Flux<Filter> filterFlux) {
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
           return Mono.from(
                   filterFlux.map(filter -> FILTERS.get(filter.getKey()).apply(filter))
                             .map(f ->  new Query(criteria.andOperator(f)))
           );
        }
```

Filter class

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Filter {
    String key;
    Object value;
}
```

Test cases

```
Flux<Filter> filterFlux = Flux.just(new Filter("NAME", "john"), new Filter("AGE", 19));

createQueryWithFilters(filterFlux)
        .subscribe(val -> System.out.println(val.toString()));
```